# How to think about and plan an hd5f file for my purposes

Tags: python, optimization, data-structures, hdf5, b-tree

**The data:**
The data I am starting with is several dozen tab-delimited text files, 6-10 GB each (way bigger than I can work with in physical memory). 
Each of these files has five columns, with two discrete variables (var1 and var2) and three continuous variables (var3,4,and 5).
Each row is expected to have a unique combination of the two discrete variables.
There are a different number of rows in each file, as not all var1-var2 combinations are present in all files.

**My final goal:**
For each unique var1-var2 combination, measure the consistency of each continuous variable (vars 3-5) across data files. I want to identify var1-var2 combinations where vars3-5 are most and least consistent across files.

**My basic strategy:**
 1. Merge each file side-by side such that where the var1-var2 pair is missing for a given file, that row gets filled with NaN for the columns corresponding to the file where it was missing (I believe the correct term for this is “full outer join” with Var1 and Var2 as keys)
 2. Take the merged file, and for each row, and get correlations for each variable across origin files.

**Why this hasn't worked so far:** 
 3. I can't merge the files using Python Pandas or R, because they are too big to fit into memory.
 4. I don't see how it would work to chunk by a set number of rows, because I don't know how many missing rows are in each file, which means that the files could drift out of alignment as I go through the file, causing the merge to fail because the same pair of keys end up in different chunks in different files.

**Is HDF5 the solution, and if so, how should I organize it for my purpose?:**
HDF5 files seem to be a way around this problem, but I don't understand the way their hierarchy would be applied to this situation (I'm still trying to get my head around the whole concept of how an h5 file is structured). 
From what I've read, I think the hierarchy should go something like this:

Level 1: Var1 values (there are tens of thousands or more of them).

Level 2:  Var2 values (there are thousands or more potential values, but usually less than 50 for each Var1).

Level 3:  Column names of the continuous variables (vars 3-5)

Level 4: Value for each of the files.

After setting up an h5 file like this, compute correlations between values at each level 4 node (ie values  for a particular var1-var2-(var3 or var4 or var5) combination.

Do I seem to be understanding how an hd5f file is structured, and if so, is this the right structure given my purpose?